# Making a smaller dataframe from a large dataframe by selecting specific row elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like following

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 |
| A | 2 | 20 |
| A | 3 | 30 |
| B | 1 | 10 |
| B | 2 | 20 |
| C | 4 | 40 |
| C | 5 | 70 |

I want the output like the following

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 30 |
| B | 2 | 20 |
| C | 5 | 70 |

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df.sort_values('Col2').drop_duplicates('Col1')
Out[58]: 
  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A     1    10
3    B     1    10
5    C     4    40
```

Comment: I want to get the row where Col2 value is highest. How can I do that?

Comment: By using ascending=false ?